# Laravel: How to get data from 3 tables with relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have 3 Tables:

`Customers`

- id
- name

`Sales`

- customer_id
- sale_date

`Contacts`

- customer_id
- contact_date

There aren't any update operations in the `contacts` table. Each process opens a new record in the `contacts` table. So, a user can have more than one records in the `contacts` table.

Here are my relations in models:

`Customer`

```
public function contacts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Contact::class);
}

public function sales()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Sale::class);
}
```

`Contact`

```
public function customer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer', 'customer_id');
}
```

`Sale`

```
public function customer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
}
```

I would like to have the latest record of the `contacts` table and make it join with the other related tables.

Here is the query which I have tried:

```
$record = Contact::groupBy('customer_id')
        ->select(DB::raw('max(id)'));

$result = Customer::query();
$result->where('is_active', 'YES');
$result->with('sales');
$result->whereHas('contacts', function ($q) use($record){
        return $q->whereIn('id', $record)->where('result', 'UNCALLED');
    });
return $result->get();
```

In the blade file, I get some result in `foreach` loops. However, I am unable to get the related data from the `sales` and `contacts` table.

```
@foreach($result as $item)
@foreach($item->sales as $sale) // Has no output and gives error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() 
@foreach($item->contacts as $contact) // Has no output and gives error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Can anyone help me how to display the sale and contact date? Or any idea for how to improve this code quality?

Comment: Have you tried the `protected $with` property in your eloquent model?

Comment: Quick note; relationship names should reflect how many results are being returned. You have `contact` and `sale`, both of which use `hasMany()` and returns more than one, so those really should be `contacts` and `sales` to avoid confusion. `customer` is good, as `belongsTo()` inherently returns a single record.

Comment: @TimLewis Yes, you're right. Sorry for the misspell. I corrected it.

Comment: No worries! Just make sure to fix references too; `$item->sales` instead of `$item->sale` and `$item->contacts` instead of `$item->contact`

Comment: @MadameGreenPea how are you sending the results to the view ?

Comment: @N69S The query function I shared above is in the file which I'm using it as a repository. I call the function from the controller and then return view. 
`return view('admin.customer.list', compact('result'));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the latest record of the contacts you can declare another relationship on the `Customer` model, e.g.:

```php
public function latest_contact()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Contact::class)->latest('contact_date');
}
```

BTW you can always declare one or more `hasOne` additional relationship if you have a `hasMany` in place the *foreign key* used is the same.

In this way you can retrieve `latest_contact` *eager loaded* with your `Customer` model:

```php
$customer = Customer::with('latest_contact')->find($id);
```

Or use this relationship in your queries, something like that:

```php
$customers = Customer::where('is_active', 'YES')
    ->with('sales')
    ->with('contacts')
    ->whereHas('last_contact', function ($q){
        return $q->where('result', 'UNCALLED');
    })->get();
```

Or that:

```php
$customers = Customer::where('is_active', 'YES')
    ->with('sales')
    ->with('contacts')
    ->with('last_contact', function ($q){
        return $q->where('result', 'UNCALLED');
    })->get();
```

If you want you can declare `last_contact` with the additional `where`:

```php
public function latest_contact()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Contact::class)
        ->where('result', 'UNCALLED')
        ->latest('contact_date');
}
```

This way all other queries should be easier.
I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks. But, I still cannot get the sale date and contact date in the view file. So, unfortunately, the result is the same. I don't understand why.

Comment: Well the idea is simple: with a `hasMany` relationship you can declare others `hasOne` and `hasMany` on the same model with additional conditions, try to play with that idea and your data, your queries should be easier.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure, but can you try to do the following:

```
return Customer::where('is_active', 'YES')
    ->with([
        'sale', 
        'contact' => function ($query) use($record) {
            return $query->whereIn('id', $record)->where('result', 'UNCALLED');
        }
    ])->get();
```

Comment: This will return all active `Customer` records, but the original question is adding additional filtering using `->whereHas()`, so this is an incorrect approach. You cause use `->with()` at the same time as `->whereHas()` to limit the returned results of `->contact`, but omitting it is wrong.